# Windows feature installation fails with "The source files could not be found"

Tags: installation, windows-server-2012-r2

I am trying to install the `Media Foundation` feature onto a Windows 2012 R2 box in preparation for it to be used as an RDS Session Host.

However, all attempts to install fail with:
`Installation of one or more roles, role services, or features failed. The source files could not be found. Use the "Source" option to specify the location of the files that are required to restore the feature. For more information on specifying a source location, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=243077. Error: 0x800f081f`

Please find the dism and cbs logs [-->here<--](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=4A216B3028AA2EA4!245&authkey=!AMgEn4VZDYAE798&ithint=folder%2clog)

The Windows box is fully up2date as of today with all Windows Updates.
I have specified the file location as `WIM:F:\sources\install.wim:4`, where F:\ is the mounted Windows DVD (tried RTM + Update1 DVD's). There is a WSUS on the Network, and the Policy is set to:

`Never attempt to download payload from Windows Update: Disabled`

`Contact Windows Update directly to download repair content instead of Windows Server Update Services (WSUS): Enabled`

I have installed other features successfully using this method before.

I also tried *with* and *without* specifying a source with the same result.

I did a CheckSUR to make sure that the component store is not corrupt.

The Windows Installation is one which had the local file store removed (Features on Demand) to keep the footprint small. (i.e. `Get-WindowsFeature | Where-Object {$_.Installed –eq $False} | Uninstall-WindowsFeature -Remove`)

Unfortunately, I don't really know what to do from the errors in the log file.

I can see instances of:

> 2014-07-23 16:28:22, Info                  CBS    Failed to internally
>   open package. [HRESULT = 0x800f0805 - CBS_E_INVALID_PACKAGE]
>
> 2014-07-23 16:28:22, Info                  CBS    Failed to
>   OpenPackage using worker session [HRESULT = 0x800f0805]

I can see that it downloads some packages but has some troubles there:

> 2014-07-23 16:27:03, Info                  CBS    DWLD: Bundled index
>   = 1
>
> 2014-07-23 16:27:03, Info                  CBS    DWLD: Windows update server URL:
>   http://download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/software/updt/2014/05/windows8.1-kb2965500-x64_df916a7e348b2d53dbdc8e7f1828d0d1f7b5c3ca.cab
>
> 2014-07-23 16:27:03, Info                  CBS    DWLD:Content is
>   Full-Cab package.
>
> 2014-07-23 16:27:03, Info                  CBS
>   Failed to copy to path on bundle: 1 [HRESULT = 0x80246013 - Unknown
>   Error]
>
> 2014-07-23 16:27:03, Info                  CBS    WU: WSUS
>   service is the default, URL: (null), Name: Windows Server Update
>   Service

as well as:

> 2014-07-23 16:28:24, Info                  CBS    Exec: Processing
>   complete.  Session: 30385793_3994419723, Package:
>   Microsoft-Windows-ServerCore-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.3.9600.16384
>   [HRESULT = 0x800f081f - CBS_E_SOURCE_MISSING]
>
> 2014-07-23 16:28:24,
>   Error                 CBS    Failed to perform operation.  [HRESULT =
>   0x800f081f - CBS_E_SOURCE_MISSING]
>
> 2014-07-23 16:28:24, Info
>   CBS    Session: 30385793_3994419723 finalized. Download error:
>   0x800f094b [CBS_E_SOURCE_MISSING_FROM_WUSUS_BYPASS_EXPRESS], Reboot
>   required: no [HRESULT = 0x800f081f - CBS_E_SOURCE_MISSING]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by:

- Mounting the `C:\` drive of another VM which has not removed the OnDemand features
- Pointing to that drive's Windows directory (i.e. `H:\Windows` in my case)

doing that, the feature installed correctly...

Answer (score 3):

I'm working also on virtualized environment.
I followed the procedure described [Here](http://woshub.com/how-to-install-net-framework-3-5-in-windows-server-2012-r2/).

The idea is to specify the alternate path sources :
`YOUR_INSTALLATION_DISK_LETTER:\sources\sxs`
For me it is :
`D:\sources\sxs`

Comment: The important part here is the `sxs` subdirectory rather than just e.g. `D:\sources` which appeared correct when I first tried!